# Error with lm and quantmod in R

Tags: r, lm, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I seem to be getting an error in R when trying to write a simple linear regression based pairs trading code. I suspect this may be an error coming from the downloaded data? However, I'm unsure of whether I am right or how to deal with the bug. As you can probably see, I am relatively new to this sort of thing in R. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated.

```
symbols <- c("GOLDBEES.NS", "NIFTYBEES.NS")
getSymbols(symbols)

#[1] "GOLDBEES.NS"  "NIFTYBEES.NS"
startT  <- "2011-01-01"
endT    <- "2014-01-01"
rangeT  <- paste(startT,"::",endT,sep ="")
tGOLDBEES   <- GOLDBEES.NS[,6][rangeT]
tNIFTYBEES   <- NIFTYBEES.NS[,6][rangeT]
startO  <- "2014-02-01"
endO <- "2016-04-01"
rangeO  <- paste(startO,"::",endO,sep ="")
oGOLDBEES   <- GOLDBEES.NS[,6][rangeO]
oNIFTYBEES   <- NIFTYBEES.NS[,6][rangeO]
pdtGOLDBEES <- diff(tGOLDBEES)[-1]
pdtNIFTYBEES <- diff(tNIFTYBEES)[-1]
model <- lm(pdtGOLDBEES ~ pdtNIFTYBEES - 1)
#Error in model.frame.default(formula = pdtGOLDBEES ~ pdtNIFTYBEES - 1,         
#:   variable lengths differ (found for 'pdtNIFTYBEES')
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this seems to be the source of the problem, the lengths are 412 and 580, respectively. Do you know how to go about solving this problem? The error is from the data sets, yes?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi just checked... 
`> nrow(GOLDBEES.NS)
[1] 1742
> nrow(NIFTYBEES.NS)
[1] 1925`

Comment: @Rob It's at the bottom of the code above.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yep, I see that now. Thanks. I find it strange that this would be the case given the same dates. Do you know of any solution to this problem that I can implement? Or do I need to just go in and fix the data sets manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noticed, `nrow(GOLDBEES.NS)` gives 1742 while `nrow(NIFTYBEES.NS)` gives 1925. Let's have a closer look:

```
a <- attr(GOLDBEES.NS, "index")
a <- as.integer((a - a[1]) / 86400)    # number of days since 2008-01-01
b <- attr(NIFTYBEES.NS, "index")
b <- as.integer((b - b[1]) / 86400)    # number of days since 2008-01-01
```

You don't really have consecutive daily observations. We should only work with data from common dates.

```
GOLDBEES.NS <- GOLDBEES.NS[a %in% b]
NIFTYBEES.NS <- NIFTYBEES.NS[b %in% a]
nrow(GOLDBEES.NS)  # 1740
nrow(NIFTYBEES.NS)  # 1740
```

Now you can use your code:

```
startT  <- "2011-01-01"
endT    <- "2014-01-01"
rangeT  <- paste(startT,"::",endT,sep ="")
tGOLDBEES   <- GOLDBEES.NS[,6][rangeT]
tNIFTYBEES   <- NIFTYBEES.NS[,6][rangeT]
pdtGOLDBEES <- diff(tGOLDBEES)[-1]
pdtNIFTYBEES <- diff(tNIFTYBEES)[-1]
model <- lm(pdtGOLDBEES ~ pdtNIFTYBEES - 1)

#Call:
#lm(formula = pdtGOLDBEES ~ pdtNIFTYBEES - 1)

#Coefficients:
#pdtNIFTYBEES  
#     -0.6383
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, super helpful. Will try this out later today.